# dibujar semicírculos y conectar los valores a una variable

Tags: swift

estoy haciendo un circulo que se dibuje con coordenadas de los ejes (X, Y),lo que quiero hacer es un cono pero que se dibuje con las entradas de datos que se ingrese(diámetro Mayor,menor y altura), he intentado de todo pero no lo consigo, si alguien me puede decir como o orientar se lo agradecería.
lo que quiero que se dibuje es esto imagen de abajo, imagen muestra coordenadas x,y. gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el código que intentaste?

Comment: no tengo código por eso pido la ayuda, lo que hago es colocar una imagen de referencia y calcula los valores, pero la imagen es estática por lo tanto cuando cambian los grados  la imagen siempre es la misma, la idea es que si cambian los datos la imagen se dibuje como si fuera real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te puedes ayudar de la función para dibujar un arco que ya viene en Swift. Creas una función que reciba como parámetros: ángulo inicial, ángulo final, radio y como adicional sería el color.

Esta función va a dibujar el arco gris y negro del diámetro mayor y del diámetro menor.

```
func drawArc(startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, radio: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: (self.view.window?.layer.frame.width)!/2, y: (self.view.window?.layer.frame.height)!/2), radius: radio, startAngle: (startAngle * .pi / 180), endAngle: (endAngle * .pi / 180), clockwise: false)
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

Es importante que tranformes a radianes los grados:

```
(startAngle * .pi / 180)
```

Esta función es para dibujar la línea del eje `x`:

```
func drawLine() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 10, y: Int((self.view.window?.layer.frame.height)!)/2, width: Int((self.view.window?.layer.frame.width)!) - 20, height: 0))
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

Para calcular el centro de la pantalla haces el siguiente cálculo:

```
(self.view.window?.layer.frame.height)!)/2
(self.view.window?.layer.frame.width)!)/2
```

Llamas a las funciones cuando ya se muestre la vista:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //base mayor
        drawArc(startAngle: 0, endAngle: 180, radio: 100, color: .gray)
        //diámetro mayor
        drawArc(startAngle: 340, endAngle: 200, radio: 100, color: .black)
        //base menor
        drawArc(startAngle: 0, endAngle: 180, radio: 40, color: .gray)
        //diámetro menor
        drawArc(startAngle: 340, endAngle: 200, radio: 40, color: .black)
        drawLine()
    }
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**
Debes tener cuidado con los grados que vienen en sentido antihorario desde la derecha (360), por eso el arco negro empieza desde la derecha en 340 y termina en 200.

**Editado líneas inclinadas**

Para las líneas inclinadas debes usar funciones trigonométricas como `sin` y `cos`. Esta es la función para dibujar las líneas; recibe como parámetros el ángulo, radio y el color como las otras funciones:

```
func drawLine(angle: Double, radio: Double, color: UIColor) {
        let originX = (self.view.window?.layer.frame.width)! / 2
        let originY = (self.view.window?.layer.frame.height)! / 2
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: originX, y: originY)
        let radAngle: Double = (angle * .pi) / 180
        //Aquí calculas la inclinación de acuerdo al ángulo y radio.
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: originX + sin(radAngle) * radio,
                               y: originY + cos(radAngle) * radio)
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: endPoint)
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
        
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

El llamado a la nueva función es la siguiente:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //base mayor
        drawArc(startAngle: 0, endAngle: 180, radio: 100, color: .gray)
        //diámetro mayor
        drawArc(startAngle: 340, endAngle: 200, radio: 100, color: .black)
        //base menor
        drawArc(startAngle: 0, endAngle: 180, radio: 40, color: .gray)
        //diámetro menor
        drawArc(startAngle: 340, endAngle: 200, radio: 40, color: .black)
        //eje x
        drawLine()
        //líneas de vértices
        drawLine(angle: 110, radio: 100, color: .black)
        drawLine(angle: 250, radio: 100, color: .black)
        drawLine(angle: 110, radio: 40, color: .gray)
        drawLine(angle: 250, radio: 40, color: .gray)
    }
```

El nuevo resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**
Aquí el sentido de los ángulos cambia (no sé por qué Apple lo hace así), ahora empieza desde abajo hacia la derecha, es decir que el ángulo de noventa grados lo tendrás en la línea del eje `x` desde la derecha.

Comment: lo que necesito son los dos circulo negros que estén unidos por sus vertices, las otras lineas son solo para mostrar las medidas,escribeme :luisolivare964@gmail.com

Comment: @LuisOlivare te adjunté la nueva función. He recordado algunas cosas de trigonometría :D. Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: es de mucha ayuda, me podrías aclarar como conectar los grados a los TextField para dibujar los arcos ya que los arcos dependen de los diámetros de entrada que van a crecer o achicar dependiendo de su valor de entrada. (los radios siempre van a cambiar y de acuerdo a eso se debe de dibujar)

Comment: Los valores de los parámetros que envías a cada función los cambias con los `textField`.

Comment: no he podido conectar los valores del radio:100 de DrawArc a una variable para que pueda cambiar su radio , y así se dibuje según los datos de entrada(los datos de entrada los guardo en una variable) y radio:debe de recibir el valor de la variable al igual que los diámetros